# Android: Layout overlap with the touch screen icons

Tags: android

I have a simple `LinearLayout`. The layout is being overlapped by the touch icons at the bottom of the device and emulator.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

How to fix this? Is this a system level setting?

[image]

Comment: Try by add '<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>' in your style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in entire project, you can use in style like this:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:ignore="NewApi">false</item>
```

Or, if you want it in a particular activity rather than entire project, you can use like this also:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your linear layout attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use scrollview instead of LinearLayout.check following code.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```